# pyspark dataframe: remove some whole words but case insensitive in a column

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to remove some whole words (but case insensitive) in a pyspark dataframe column.

```
import re
s = "I like the book. i'v seen it. Iv've" # add a new phrase
exclude_words = ["I", "I\'v", "I\'ve"]

exclude_words_re = re.compile(r"\b(" + r"|".join(exclude_words) +r")\b|\s", re.I|re.M)
exclude_words_re.sub("" , s)
```

I added

```
 "Iv've"
```

but, got:

```
'like the book. seen it.'
```

"Iv've" should not be removed because it does not match any whole words in exclude_words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 changes to implement to your code:

1. Use proper regex flags to ignore case
2. Add `\b` to only include whole words.

```
import re
s = "I like the book. i'v seen it. Iv've I've"
exclude_words = ["I", "I\'v", "I\'ve"]


exclude_words_re = re.compile(r"(^|\b)((" + r"|".join(exclude_words) +r"))(\s|$)", re.I|re.M)
exclude_words_re.sub("" , s)

"like the book. seen it. Iv've "
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please see my UPDATE in OP. Some unmatched words are also removed even though it is not in the "exclude_words". thanks!

Comment: Updated @user3448011